# Tidying function template to avoid duplication: decltype issues

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class which wraps a member function:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class testclass {
public:
    double get() { return d_; }
    void set(double d) { d_ = d; }
    double d_ = 0.0;
};

template<typename Retriever, Retriever retrieverFunc, typename Updater, Updater updaterFunc, typename OwningClass>
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(Retriever retriever, Updater updater, OwningClass* owner) : retriever_(retriever), updater_(updater), containingClass_(owner) {}

    using GetterReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(retrieverFunc), OwningClass>;
    GetterReturnType Get() { return (containingClass_->*retriever_)(); }

    template<typename...Args>
    using SetterReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(updaterFunc), OwningClass, Args...>;

    template<typename...Args>
    SetterReturnType<Args...> Set(Args&&... args) { return (containingClass_->*updater_)((forward<Args>(args))...); }

    Retriever retriever_;
    Updater updater_;
    OwningClass* containingClass_;
};


int main() {

    testclass tc;

    Wrapper<decltype(&testclass::get), &testclass::get, decltype(&testclass::set), &testclass::set, testclass> pp(&testclass::get, &testclass::set, &tc);
    pp.Get();
    pp.Set(1.0);

}
```

Clearly, the syntax for declaring a wrapper is a bit tedious, so I wanted to clean it up a bit.  I tried this:

```
template<typename Retriever, Wrapper Updater, typename OwningClass>
using WrapperSimplified = Wrapper<decltype(Retriever), Retriever, decltype(Updater), Updater, OwningClass>;
```

with the intention of being able to say this:

```
WrapperSimplified<&testclass::get, &testclass::set, testclass> pp(&testclass::get, &testclass::set, &tc);
```

But it does not compile, VS2022 complains

'Retriever': is not a valid type for non-type template parameter 'retrieverFunc'

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: Why does the class take a `Retriever` and `Updater` as non-type template parameter, but also as constructor parameter? That doesn't seem to make any sense. `retrieverFunc` and `updaterFunc` seem to be completely unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Retriever` is supposed to be the value, not the type, of the non-type template argument. So it should be declared as non-type template parameter. Since you want the type to be deduced, the type of the non-type template parameter should be `auto`. Equivalently for `Updater`:

```
template<auto Retriever, auto Updater, typename OwningClass>
using WrapperSimplified = Wrapper<decltype(Retriever), Retriever, decltype(Updater), Updater, OwningClass>;
```

---

But from what I can tell the class doesn't actually use the non-type template parameters `retrieverFunc` and `updaterFunc`. You can remove them (replacing the `decltype(retrieverFunc)` with `Retriever` and `decltype(updaterFunc)` with `Updater`).

Then the class object can be created simply using CTAD:

```
Wrapper pp(&testclass::get, &testclass::set, &tc);
```

Comment: Thanks.  If you could also advise at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72929601, I'd appreciate it greatly.